# How to query AWS to get ELB names and attached instances to that using python boto modules?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I am trying retrieve the ELB names and the attached instances ids using python boto modules.

```
{
    import boto

    conn = boto.connect_elb()
    conn.get_all_load_balancers()
}
```

Gives only load-balancer names now how can i retrieve the Instance-ids attached to the load-balancer ?

Comment: in plain CLI it would be `aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-name <name_of_your_lb> --query LoadBalancerDescriptions[].Instances` you can translate that into python code

Answer (score 3):

`conn.get_all_load_balancers()` - returns a list of elbs objects. Each elb object has a parameter `instances` that will show you attached instances. And from there you can get their Id's.
If you want to find elb by name, then you need to filter first loop.

So something like this should work (Thanks @Frédéric Henri for update):

```
import boto

conn = boto.connect_elb()
elbs = conn.get_all_load_balancers(load_balancer_names=['MY-ELB-NAME'])[0]
instances = [inst.id for elb in elbs for inst in elb.instances]
```

Comment: you can filter by name already no ? something like `conn.get_all_load_balancers(load_balancer_names=['MY-ELB-NAME'])`

Comment: @FrédéricHenri: First i like you to thank for the reply.
Actually i tried the above given steps was getting an error.
**AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'instances'**.

Comment: @Manzoor I think its an array did you try `elbs = conn.get_all_load_balancers(load_balancer_names=['MY-ELB-NAME'])[0]`